# What are double groups mathematically?

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, mp.mathematical-physics, mathematical-chemistry

In physics and chemistry, there is the concept of [double groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_group). These are double covers of the usual point groups, obtained by "adding an element $R$, which represents rotation by $2\pi$" to the respective point group.

Since the set $\{ E,R \}$ forms a group isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_2$, it seems that the double group should be some kind of a product of the point group and $\mathbb Z_2$. However, it is not the direct product, since $R$ does not commute with all the elements. Can it be defined a different operation between the point group and $\mathbb Z_2$?

Comment: Is anybody able to translate the gibberish of the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_group) into a mathematical definition?

Comment: Is it not just a semidirect product? (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidirect_product)

Comment: @SamHopkins, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/464166/what-are-double-groups-mathematically#comment1205239_464166), it is an extension by $\mathbb Z/2$, but it need not split.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As far as I can tell, a *double group* is a double cover of a group. Specifically, if $G \subset \operatorname{SO}(n)$ is a group acting by rotations of $n$-dimensional space, its *double group* is the lift $2G \subset \operatorname{Spin}(n)$ defined as the fibre product
$$2G = G \times_{\operatorname{SO}(n)} \operatorname{Spin}(n).$$
It seems that this language is only used when $n=3$ and $G$ is finite. (The *point group* is the symmetries of a lattice that preserve a point.) Probably chemists don't know about higher-dimensional spaces.

Comment: Probably the mathematical content of this answer can do without the funny but unnecessary dig at chemists at the end.

Comment: Since some chemical structures are symmetrical under reflections, I would guess sometimes $G$ may be a subgroup of $\mathrm{O}(n)$ instead of $\mathrm{SO}(n)$, in which case the spin group could be replaced with a pin group. But which one?

Comment: Less snarkily put: Chemists are less concerned with such groups in higher dimensions.

Comment: @WillSawin Good question. I don't know much chemistry, just a little physics, so I can only speculate. My guess is that what you want to know is the possible eigendistributions of electrons, where you know that you have n electrons per site of your lattice. This is basically a question about the representation theory of the point group: the final answer will be a free module for the translation group, so it will be induced up from a representation of the point group (aka little group). If you have an odd number of electrons, then you need to look at spin representations aka reps of the ...

Comment: ... double group 2G for which the central character is nontrivial. Now you ask: what if the point group includes reflections? You might try to dismiss the question as follows. The electron is a Dirac fermion: it is not invariant under any time-reversing symmetry. In a *relativistic* unitary quantum field theory, this implies also that the electron is not invariant under and space-reflecting symmetries. I'm telling you something nontrivial: I'm telling you that if you have a unitary representation of the time-preserving but possibly-space-reflecting subgroup of Lorentz group, then it extends...

Comment: ... canonically to a unitary-and-antiunitary representation of the full Lorentz group. The existence and uniqueness of this extension is what you should think of if you hear people talk about "CRT theorem" (usually called "CPT theorem", but that "theorem" only holds in odd dimensions where P is a product of odd-many R's --- P := diag(-1,-1,...,-1) \in O(n), and R is any reflection in a single direction). So the point is that even if your crystal has a space-reflecting symmetry, the electron cloud has no reason to: it spontaneously breaks spatial reflection.

Comment: But that's a dismissive response. Here is what I think the actual answer is. The actual answer is probably: "It doesn't matter which of the Pin groups you use". The reason is that what you care about is the block of Rep(2G) in which the centre acts nontrivially. This block is the same for both Pin groups. Indeed, it is the same as a Rep(G)-module category. Indeed, if you arbitrarily choose a $\sqrt{-1}$, then, writing $2_\pm G$ for the $\mathrm{Pin}_\pm$-cover of $G \subset \mathrm{O}(n)$, what you find is that every $2_+ G$-module is also canonically a $2_- G$-module, and conversely. The ...

Comment: ... only difference is the fusion (aka tensor product). As I said, if you fuse a fermionic module (one with central character -1) with a bosonic module (one with central character +1), then that doesn't care about whether you think of them as $2_+ G$-modules or $2_- G$-modules. The only change is if you fuse two fermionic modules. If you translate between the Pin groups, the fusion of fermionic modules gets off by a (universal, overall) factor of the determinant $\det : G \to \mathrm{O}(1)$. This is the factor that for example exchanges the vector representation with the pseudovector.

Comment: I have a hard time imagining any experiment that can be sensitive to this overall factor. It is just some overall signs, so it does not affect norm-squared's of wave functions, which is to say it does not affect any probability densities determined by any states (pure or mixed). You can sometimes pick up subtle signs / relative scalar factors by setting up two-slit interference patterns. But I don't think in this case there's any way to arrange the necessary superposition without some magic mirror that spatially-reflects any state that goes into it.